# disabling session for django view

Tags: javascript, python, django, session, middleware

I want to create a new feature for a website that will allow the registered members to see the website as if they are not registered and see how it will look with all there changes

so how can we do something like that using django framework?

Comment: Don't think you can control sessions per view.

Comment: there should be a way to make it tread user as a not authorized user ... may adding a flag or something .. or creating an iframe .. I am not really sure how that could be done. but I am sure that it is possible

Comment: You can create an iframe which can have its own sessions. Or you will have to modify the default session middleware to accommodate your case.

Comment: I tried to create an iframe, but it seems that it uses the same session as the website and not its own.